# Changing an imageView in an Android Widget onclick

Tags: android, widget

I have a very simple widget that has a background image of a speech bubble and an imageView that contains a character standing next to it (as if he is saying something).
On top of the speech bubble i have a textView in which i show some text.

Basically all i want to do is so that when the user clicks on the character the image changes to show an animation of the character.

I did a simple app that animates an imageView (using the animation-list xml) when the image is clicked and that worked fine. So i was wondering if i could achieve the same thing with this widget.

I have seen some examples where by you can click on a widget (be it a button, image, whatever) and you can then load a config layout however i simply cant figure out and i cant find anywhere if what i want can be done.

So basically what i need to know is:
1. can a widget have an animated imageView
2. What do i need to do so that when the imageView is clicked it loads the animation?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance guys!!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use **LayoutAnimation**? See the related question here:
[Android Widgets: Animations on RemoteViews ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118233/android-widgets-animations-on-remoteview)

Comment: no, but even if i did, how would i trigger the animation when i click on the image?

Comment: I suppose you have to write something like this:


    `imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override

                public void onClick(View v) {

              
                    img.startAnimation(youAnimation);

                }

        });`


Maybe this is helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651070/how-to-make-button-with-custom-background-image-show-click-animation-in-android

Comment: I don't know exactly how is your app, but I think that maybe it's better not to use another class to do it. You can just override the onUpdate method to give extra functionality..

Comment: Yes Thanasis, thats right. Thats what i have done thank you.i cant believe its not as simple as just telling it to change the image background and use the animation list :| I mean the main problem is that with the remoteView i cant use the findViewById, so i cant assign the animation list to the imageView.